# How can I access methods/functions from another file in this way?

Tags: c++, file, methods

I am new to C++, so I would like to store a file with some methods inside that does some calculations and then I would like to call them like this, FileName.MethodName(Arguments). Is it possible to use the (.) DOT?

I am using C++ in [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).

Comment: It's possible, but not a good idea.

Comment: Can you give a psuedo code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking the wrong way. You don't want to call member functions on a file. You should use a class that wraps around the file stream which has member functions to perform the correct operations on it. Maybe if you can tell us what you're trying to do, I can better suit my answer to your intentions.

Comment: i would like to have a group of functions called MathFunctions , and inside i can have the SquareRoot functions so what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: @user3317215 You can have a class called `Math` with static methods like `sqrt`, `pow`, etc. BTW the standard library already has these functions.